# PyQt5: Не запускается designer.exe

Tags: python, pyqt5

Установил `PyQt5` и `pyqt5-tools` через `pip`, попытался запустить через этот путь: **C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\pyqt5_tools\designer.exe**
Погрузилось 1-2 секунды и ничего. Совсем. Попытался запустить напрямую через админа - ничего. Никакой из других инструментов как *assistant.exe* тоже не работают. `Python` версии `3.7.4` .

Comment: а что вы получаете, если просто в командной строке 
(находясь в произвольном каталоге, например `C:`) 
наберете и запустите `C:\>designer.exe` ?

Comment: @S.Nick, таким образом он тоже не запускался, но решение проблемы я нашёл...

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что у я установил версию `Python 64-bit`! Полностью удалил его и установил версию `32-bit`, после чего всё прекрасно заработало.